# Pagination issue using React Router v4.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-router

I'm migrating a site in ASP.NET MVC to REACT. And for pagination i have created a component in React.
Issue i'm facing is with Routing for the pagination URLs. React Router is not able to detect that the URL is different when i click on a pagination URL
Let me explain:

app.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import allReducers from '../reducers/index';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import ReduxPromiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './main';
import Layout from './layout';

const app = document.getElementById('root');
const store = createStore(allReducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxPromiseMiddleware));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                    <BrowserRouter>                    
                        <Layout>
                            <Main/>
                        </Layout>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </Provider>
                ,app);
```

Main component render:

```
render(){

        return(
            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>                    
                    <Route path='/posts' component={PostsRouter} />                                        
                    <Route path='/studies' component={StudiesPage} />
                </Switch>
            </main>
        );
    }
```

PostsRouter component:

```
const PostsRouter = () => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/posts' component={PostsPage} />
      <Route path='/posts/:page' component={PostsPage} />
    </Switch>
);
```

For both */posts* and */posts/2* i need the component to be *PostsPage*.
Lets say i'm at */home*. Now i click a posts link and URL changes to */posts*. Now if i click */posts/2* link, nothing happens. React Router doesn't detect that the URL is different.

And a weird thing i noted is that if i change the component:

```
<Route path='/posts/:page' component={PostsPage} /> 
to 
<Route path='/posts/:page' component={StudiesPage} />
```

then React Router routes me to StudiesPage component if i click on */posts/2* link when i'm on */posts* URL.

May be i'm missing something obvious. But i haven't been able to figure out a way after lots of attempts.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or a git repository? Just something to show some more code?

Comment: This code is yet to be added to a repository. Please tell me what you would like to see. I can add it in the question.

Comment: Try to check you `PostsPage` component. Possibly it has some problem with `this.state` updating. I mean that it may be updates but gets the same content. Try to check it out.

Comment: @Boney Did you ever get this working? I'm doing something extremely similar and am running into the same problem!

Comment: @VirtualWolf. Unfortunately i didn't get a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect Sergey's comment was right, that's what my problem ended up being. I was fetching data within `componentDidMount()` but didn't realise that in order to actually update it with new data when the next page link was clicked, I needed to do the same thing inside `componentWillReceiveProps()`. You can see my full source [here](https://bitbucket.org/VirtualWolfCo/virtualwolf.cloud/src/d72013f0e3ec63d2636fc26feef11458619bfb69/src/components/Media.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) but the biggest key part was this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        loaded: false
    });
    this.fetchMediaItems(nextProps.match.params.page);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchMediaItems(this.props.match.params.page);
}
```

`componentWillReceiveProps()` receives the new properties, including page number, when you click on the link to page 2, so you need to do whatever inside there to update with the new state.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was working on a different stuff for a long time. Yes, you are right. "componentWillReceiveProps()" was getting invoked, but i was not aware since i had my code only in "componentWillMount()". Thanks a lot for your help. Paging is working for me now.

Comment: In the latest version of react "componentWillReceiveProps" is deprecated. You should use componentDidUpdate instead. Also don't forget to compare previous prop with this props otherwise it can go in infinite loop.